# Android app for 1st timer

Tags: android

I'm new in as an android developer so, I'm learnig through the developer.android tutorial and one question is constantly hitting me is that, like in every sub part of tutorial it says "you themes.xml file should look like this", I was wondering do I replace the file every time as I move forward to the course or just add the contents(I got duplicate errors which sounds legit!) because the tutorial doesn't say anything and as a result I'm getting whole bunch of compiling errors. I would really appreciate if somebody can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should link the tutorial to allow others to specifically what you are looking at.

Comment: In most scenarios, add the content to yours. However, Android (particularly Android Studios) has changed a bit in the last few months - especially with Lollipop out - so it may just be that the tutorials need to be updated regarding the themes file (it's usually the theme name/path that's the issue).

Comment: Although, if you're going through the official developer.android.com tutorials, they should be updated (but no promises). Just a note for the future~

Comment: I tried doing both of them..but still getting lots of errors.. My first stage was ok but problem arised from the second one..

Answer (score -1):

What Tutorial are you using? Each activity might be different from the previous, but I imagine it'll tell you if it's just a continuation from a previous activity.

Comment: I'm using the official one!